# PhoneGap 3.3 HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar not working

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using PhoneGap 3.3.0-0.19.6 and Cordova 3.3.1-0.4.2 but HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar=true doesn't work. I checked other related questions and the solution (at least for PhoneGap 2.7) is to edit CDViewController.m (under Classes/Cleaver), but apparently this file is missing in Phonegap 3.3

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I use [KeyBoard plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard) to fix this problem. (I'm currently in phonegap 3.4.0)

To download it, either

- Type 'cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins.git#dev:keyboard' in your project folder
- Or type 'phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.keyboard', and update the newest code from KeyBoard plugin.

For Further infomation, visit phonegap CB-3020 jira. (sorry, I not allow to post more than 2 links)

Good Luck!

Comment: The `cordova plugin add` command doesn't work. Try `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins.git#master:keyboard` instead